# with a high density or with high density?

Tags: articles

I wrote this sentence.

We study large-scale graphs with a high density or with high density?

Which one is right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I meant to say was that the common attribute(high density) belongs to the entire plural noun(graphs). Not just one of the plural noun (1 graph)!

We'd say:

> "All the trees have leaves!"

We'd not say

> "All the trees have a leaf!"  Do we?

Comment: How could the high density refer to the subject in either option? That doesn't make any sense!

Comment: It depends on your context of understanding. Please refer below: